# Python add date value to column based on conditions

Tags: python, logic, python-datetime

And thank you in advanced for the help.

Current pd.Dataframe:

| event_name | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Start | 2010-11-12 | 2015-01-05 |
| Phase 1 | 2015-01-05 | 2015-03-16 |
| Phase 2 | 2015-04-04 | 2018-03-11 |
| Phase 3 | 2018-03-11 | 2030-05-15 |
| Phase 4 | 2030-05-15 | 2035-01-01 |
| Phase 5 | 2035-01-01 | 2035-04-01 |
| Checkpoint | 2025-12-25 | NaT |

---

Expected pd.Dataframe:

| event_name | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Start | 2010-11-12 | 2015-01-05 |
| Phase 1 | 2015-01-05 | 2015-03-16 |
| Phase 2 | 2015-04-04 | 2018-03-11 |
| Phase 3 | 2018-03-11 | 2030-05-15 |
| Phase 4 | **2030-05-15** | 2035-01-01 |
| Phase 5 | 2035-01-01 | 2035-04-01 |
| Checkpoint | 2025-12-25 | **2030-05-15** |

Logic:

'Checkpoint' end_date needs to either be the start_date for 'Phase 4' OR the start_date for 'Phase 5'.
If either of those aren't present, then the end_date for 'Checkpoint' will be 30 days after the start_date.

Thank you again!

I've tried various forms of df.loc. But I cannot get the logic to work.

d_end = df.loc[(df['evet_name']== "Phase 4") | (df['event_name']== "Phase 5"), ['event_name','start_date']]
d_end = pd.DataFrame(d_end)
print("Printing d_end test {}".format((d_end)))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @СергейКох added some code.

Comment: where did you get the 'name' column from?

Comment: @СергейКох That would be 'event_name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since accessing the missing cells by index causes an exception, we had to add checks. Example with missing phase values 4 and 5.

```
dt.txt
```

```
event_name  start_date  end_date
Start   2010-11-12  2015-01-05
Phase 1 2015-01-05  2015-03-16
Phase 2 2015-04-04  2018-03-11
Phase 3 2018-03-11  2030-05-15
Checkpoint  2025-12-25  NaT
```

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_table('dt.txt')

# We collect data on the cells we need.
phase_4_start = df.loc[df['event_name'] == 'Phase 4', 'start_date']
phase_5_start = df.loc[df['event_name'] == 'Phase 5', 'start_date']
checkpoint_start = df.loc[df['event_name'] == 'Checkpoint', 'start_date']

# We add 30 days, first converting the string to a date, then back to a string.
checkpoint_end = (pd.to_datetime(checkpoint_start, format='%Y-%m-%d') + pd.Timedelta(days=30)).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# We immediately determine the completion date in case there are no phases 4 and 5.
checkpoint_end_date = checkpoint_end.get(checkpoint_end.index[0])

# We change the end date depending on the availability of phases 4 and 5.
if not phase_5_start.empty:
    checkpoint_end_date = phase_5_start.get(phase_5_start.index[0])
if not phase_4_start.empty:
    checkpoint_end_date = phase_4_start.get(phase_4_start.index[0])

# Set the end date of the Checkpoint.
df['end_date'] = df['end_date'].mask(df['end_date'] == 'NaT', checkpoint_end_date)
print(df)

------------------------------------------

   event_name  start_date    end_date
0       Start  2010-11-12  2015-01-05
1     Phase 1  2015-01-05  2015-03-16
2     Phase 2  2015-04-04  2018-03-11
3     Phase 3  2018-03-11  2030-05-15
4  Checkpoint  2025-12-25  2026-01-24
```

Comment: Thank you @Сергей. This works. I'm now working on different scenarios regarding multiple Checkpoints. I did need to add Phase 4 & 5 to the dt.txt you provided above. But it runs very well!